# Should you re-combine split fastq files after genome assembly?

Tags: bioinformatics, fastq, genome

I've split a large fastq file into 6 or 7 smaller more 'manageable' files for genome assembly.

Would it be 'biologically correct' to now re-combine the output files (contigs.fasta) back together? Is there a more meaningful way to do this?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to use an assembler that can handle large fastq files, on adequate hardware, that is with large RAM, and fast I/O. Let the assembler software itself parallelize the assembly process if the input is larger than can fit in RAM. Prefer this single input approach to splitting the input into parts, assembling each part separately, and then "assembling" the partial outputs/contigs.

**REFERENCES:**

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5850084/

Dominguez Del Angel, V., Hjerde, E., Sterck, L., Capella-Gutierrez, S., Notredame, C., Vinnere Pettersson, O., Amselem, J., Bouri, L., Bocs, S., Klopp, C., Gibrat, J. F., Vlasova, A., Leskosek, B. L., Soler, L., Binzer-Panchal, M., & Lantz, H. (2018). Ten steps to get started in Genome Assembly and Annotation. F1000Research, 7, ELIXIR-148. https://doi.org/10.12688/f1000research.13598.1

> For genome assembly, running times and memory requirements will
> increase with the amount of data. As more data is needed for large
> genomes, there is thus also a correlation between genome size and
> running time/memory requirements. Only a small subset of available
> assembly programs can distribute the assembly into several processes
> and run them in parallel on several compute nodes. Tools that cannot
> do this tend to require a lot of memory on a single node, while
> programs that can split the process need less memory in each
> individual node, but do on the other work most efficiently when
> several nodes are available. It is therefore important to select the
> proper assembly tools early in a project, and make sure that there are
> enough available compute resources of the right type to run these
> tools.